# Can jungle biomes occur with small custom biome size?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted a survival world with diverse resources nearby, so I created a custom world with biome size 2. (1 just seems too small.) However, despite trying about a dozen seeds and flying around in custom mode, they seem to be strongly predisposed to taiga, plains, and mountains, with other biomes more rarely, and not a jungle to be found.

My daughter says that it's because the jungle trees are too big for the smaller biome, and that either they are impossible or just very, very rare. Is she right, or have the seeds just been unlucky?

If so, what is the minimum for jungles to occur?

Comment: Jungles are rare. This is how minecraft is coded. And they are usually big. But not as big as plains

Answer (score 2):

Biome size should not prevent the spawning of any biome.

First, as you are using a customized world, make sure that you have left `Biome` at `All`:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mpBxcmE.png]

---

All biomes in Minecraft fit into the following categories:

- Snow-covered
- Cold
- Medium
- Dry/warm
- Neutral

Biomes in the same category generate near each other in clumps, so it's more likely to find a Mesa next to a Savanna rather than next to a Taiga. This is probably why you're seeing a lot of cold biomes and not much else.

Jungles fit into Medium category, so you should look around Plains, Forests, Swamps, Rivers, and Beachs.

---

Other than this, jungles are fairly uncommon, so you likely need to search around more. There are some tools such as [Amidst](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262200-v3-7-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-etc-finder) that let you find certain biomes, but I don't believe they work with custom world types.